# Missing operator in query expression in Access

Tags: c#, ms-access

I have a query in Ms-Access which returns boolean. But when executing it shows "Missing operator in query expression"

```
SELECT case when exists(select due_amt from PaymentDetails where iss_id=20 and user_id=1 and ten_no=1) then cast(1 as bit) else cast(2 as bit) end
```

Where am i wrong?

Comment: Can a `BIT` have a value of 2?

Comment: @msmucker0527 I would think not. Also Access does not have a `Bit` data type (only `Boolean`), or a cast function (use `CBool()`) in this case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to write the *Case When* statement in an IIf statement.  This query returns a boolean value.

```
SELECT IIf(Nz(due_amt,0) <> 0,True,False) as blndue from PaymentDetails where iss_id=20 and user_id=1 and ten_no=1
```

Edit:
I think that the **Is Null** function may be more robust than Nz.  Here is a rewrite

```
SELECT IIf(IIf(due_amt Is Null,0,due_amt) <> 0,True,False) as blndue from PaymentDetails where iss_id=20 and user_id=1 and ten_no=1
```

Edit 2:
ADO has a special case for Null Values.  You can test for Null values with the "= Null" condition.  I got this info from this link.
http://www.techrepublic.com/article/10-tricks-for-handling-null-values-in-microsoft-access/6125114
Here should be the final rewrite...

```
SELECT IIf(IIf(due_amt = Null,0,due_amt) <> 0,True,False) as blndue from PaymentDetails where iss_id=20 and user_id=1 and ten_no=1
```

Comment: I am getting an exception while executing from ADO.NET "**Undefined function 'Nz' in expression.**".

Comment: Are you executing a query in Access or are you generating the query in .NET? Are you using a dataset?

Comment: If i execute the query in Access it works fine. If i execute from .NET using OLEDB its throwing exception.

Comment: I have changed the query like "SELECT top 1 a.blndue from (select IIf(Nz(due_amt,0) <> 0,True,False) as blndue from PaymentDetails where iss_id=20 and user_id=1 and ten_no=1) as a"

Comment: When i change to Is Null i get the output as "Error"

Comment: do you have both IIf statements?

Comment: You can't use `Nz` from outside of Access, because `Nz` is a function supplied by the Access object model, which you don't have when connecting via ADO.NET.

Comment: @Sandy I changed the answer again :)